# Meaning of the word "good" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, colloquial-language

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/EtVfoIkVSu8?t=1251). It is at 21 minute.

> Take a rat. Train it to press a lever ten times, it gets its food. Ten times it gets its food. Ten times it doesn't get its food. Ten times, you are not giving it its food. Get the rat **good and frustrated**. And with great realibility if there is another rat sitting there, it is going to sping around and bite it.

Does it mean to get the rat very frustrated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. "Good and [adjective]" means "quite [adjective]" or "sufficiently [adjective]":

> If your knife is **good and** sharp you should be able to slice a
>   tomato without squashing it.
>
> Make sure the surface is **good and** clean, or else the decal will
>   not stick to it.
>
> You don't need to buy any fancy, expensive cat food. When that cat is **good
>   and** hungry, he'll eat your cheap kibble, and meow for more.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. "Good and [adjective]" is an idiom meaning "has become very [adjective]".

Meaning 12.c of **good** in the OED:

> " c. *colloquial* (orig. *U.S.*). ***good and***: (as an intensifier of an adjective) very, exceedingly; completely."

with examples from 1885.